# How to align and set color at the same time inside a cell with python-docx

Tags: python-docx

I am trying to make a table with python-docx.
This is my desire output:

¡--OK(bold)--¡--MIDDLE(in red)--¡----RIGHT¡

And this is what I get:

¡--OK(bold)--¡MIDDLE(in red)----¡RIGHT----¡

The code that I use is:

```
    from docx import Document
    from docx.shared import RGBColor
    from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH

    document = Document()

    table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=3, style='Table Grid')
    fila = table.rows[0].cells

    # First cell: OK in bold
    texto = 'OK'
    dentro = fila[0].paragraphs[0]
    dentro.add_run(texto).bold = True
    dentro.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER

    # Second cell: Middle in red
    texto = 'MIDDLE'
    dentro = fila[1].paragraphs[0].add_run(texto)
    dentro.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
    font = dentro.font
    font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255,0,0) # Red

    # Third cell : Right
    texto = 'RIGHT'
    dentro = fila[2].paragraphs[0]
    dentro.add_run(texto)
    dentro.aligment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT

    document.save('demo.docx')
```

I have two issues: First one is that I do not get the correct alignment in the middle cell when I add the color issue. Second one is that in cells after the wrong output of middle one, the alignment does not seem to work. How can I fix it? Do I have to wait until next version (actual 0.8.10)? Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for the middle cell is different. You assign the new run to `dentro` rather than the paragraph. This causes the alignment value to be assigned to the run where it does nothing.

Change:

```
dentro = fila[1].paragraphs[0].add_run(texto)
```

to:

```
dentro = fila[1].paragraphs[0]
run = dentro.add_run(texto)
font = run.font
font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)
```

I'm not sure how to account for the `RIGHT` alignment not "taking" on the third cell; I would make this fix and then see how you go.

Comment: Thanks scanny, but your solution does not work. I have already tried it and you get AttributeError: 'Paragraph' object has no attribute 'font'

Comment: That is because font is an attribute of a run. I've edited my code above to elaborate that a bit.

Comment: Thanks again scanny. Nice and smooth. Fixing the middle did not solve the right issue, but that for me is a minor problem for me. Thanks.